# Storing an ArrayList inside a HashMap

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have the following code. What I want to do is to have an ArrayList filled using the permutation function, keep that Array in a HashMap, and start the process all over again (basically fill the HashMap with ArrayList for each key). I posted the code below however it does not work. I think this is because It's storing the same reference to the list I have declared instead of making a copy of it. I'm a C scrub and a Java newbie so any help is appreciated!

```
public class Anagrams 
{
    public static HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> permutacii = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
    public static ArrayList<String> tempList = new ArrayList<String>();


private static void permutation(String prefix, String str)
{
    int n = str.length();
    if (n == 0) 
        tempList.add(prefix);
    else 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            permutation(prefix + str.charAt(i), 
        str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i+1));
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    findAll(System.in);
}

public static void findAll(InputStream inputStream) 
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream);
    while(scanner.hasNextLine())
    {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        permutation("", line);
        permutacii.put(line, tempList);
        tempList.clear();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: All the lists are empty inside the HashMap.

Comment: You need to initialize a new `ArrayList` each time after putting one in the map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only have one List of which you store multiple references in the HashMap. And you clear that List at the end of each iteration.

One possible way to fix your problem :

```
while(scanner.hasNextLine())
{
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    tempList = new ArrayList<String>();
    permutation("", line);
    permutacii.put(line, tempList);
}
```

Though I think the code would be more readable if you make `tempList` a local variable and pass it as an argument to the `permutation` method :

```
while(scanner.hasNextLine())
{
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    ArrayList<String> tempList = new ArrayList<String>();
    permutation("", line, tempList);
    permutacii.put(line, tempList);
}
```

and modify the `permutation` accordingly :

```
private static void permutation(String prefix, String str, ArrayList<String> tempList)
{
    int n = str.length();
    if (n == 0) 
        tempList.add(prefix);
    else 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            permutation(prefix + str.charAt(i),
                        str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i+1),
                        tempList);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to add it as a parameter to the permutation function, but I was not sure on how to edit it as there're no pointers in Java. Testing the first part now :)

Comment: [] - I am still getting empty output :|

Comment: @Hydroxis Did you remove the `tempList.clear()` statement? I tested the code and it works.

Comment: Yep, just did it and it worked. Now need to debug why It's not adding the permuations for some strings given on input :/